# Call a function after clicking "Install"

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to call a certain function after clicking "Install"?

Comment: hahahahah! my bad! In my script a created a function to install a windows service and I wanted to this to be called/executed after clicking "install".

Comment: You can delete the question if you like - the link should be next to the edit and close links, under the tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any of the pre-defined [event functions](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) that exist in Inno Setup. For instance, you might want to use `CurStepChanged`. From the documentation:

> `procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep:
>   TSetupStep);` You can use this event
>   function to perform your own
>   pre-install and post-install tasks.
>
> Called with CurStep=ssInstall just
>   before the actual installation starts,
>   with CurStep=ssPostInstall just after
>   the actual installation finishes, and
>   with CurStep=ssDone just before Setup
>   terminates after a successful install.